Impersonating a specific Win32 primary group in Powershell, if I am already a member of this group (PS version of POSIX newgrp(1))
Can I impersonate a specific Win32 primary group in Powershell at runtime if I am already a member of that group, similar to UNIX/POSIX /usr/bin/newgrp (see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/newgrp.html) ?
The idea is NOT to modify the Win32 primary group of the account, I am looking for a newgrp-like functionality to switch the primary group of the current powershell to a group of which I am a member already, but do not affect other running powershell sessions.
